# Combining proxies with different EitherT in base monad

Tags: haskell, proxies, haskell-pipes

For example, having...

```
consumer :: Proxy p => () -> Consumer p a (EitherT String IO) ()
producer :: Proxy p => () -> Producer p a (EitherT ByteString IO) r
```

... how do I make this work?

```
session :: EitherT ByteString (EitherT String IO) ()
session = runProxy $ producer >-> consumer
```

**Note**: I've read [*Mixing Base Monads*](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html#g:8) in `Control.Proxy.Tutorial`. I get the first example but can't understand the contrived example. More examples, not so obvious but not so contrived, might clarify how to use `hoist` and `lift` to match any combination of base monads.

Comment: Fiddling with the type inferencer I got `session` to type check with `runProxy $ hoist lift . producer >-> hoist (hoist lift) . consumer`. I also had to create an `MFunctor` instance for `EitherT e`: `instance (EitherT e) where hoist nat = mapEitherT nat`. I'm not closing the question because I still don't get why this works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have a monad transformer stack like `MT1 MT2 MT3 M a` where `M` is the base monad.

Using `lift`, you can add a new monad transformer to the left. It can be any transformer, so let's symbolize it by `?`.

`lift :: MT1 MT2 MT3 M a -> ? MT1 MT2 MT3 M a`

Using `hoist`, you can manipulate the monad stack to the right of the leftmost element. Manipulate it how? For example by supplying a `lift`:

`hoist lift :: MT1 MT2 MT3 M a -> MT1 ? MT2 MT3 M a`

Using combinations of `hoist` and `lift`, you can insert these "wildcards" at any point in the monad transformer stack.

`hoist (hoist lift) :: MT1 MT2 MT3 M a -> MT1 MT2 ? MT3 M a`

`hoist (hoist (hoist lift)) :: MT1 MT2 MT3 M a -> MT1 MT2 MT3 ? M a`

This technique can be used to equalize the two monad stacks from your example.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of intuitive explanation I was missing about using `hoist` and `lift`.

Answer (score 5):

The [either](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/either/3.4/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html) package (where I guess your `EitherT` type is coming from) provide several functions for modifying the first argument, e.g.

```
bimapEitherT :: Functor m => (e -> f) -> (a -> b) -> EitherT e m a -> EitherT f m b
```

You can use this, along with some appropriate encoding (or decoding), to turn an `EitherT String IO a` into an `EitherT ByteString IO a` (or vice versa), then `hoist` that transformation into the `Consumer` or `Producer` monad transformer.

Comment: Actually I was using `String` and `ByteString` as examples of different types. In practice I'm dealing with exceptions. I guess I could use `toException` so that turn all exceptions into `SomeException` but still I would like to differentiate the from which proxy the exception is coming.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually two solutions.

The first solution is the one Daniel Wagner proposed: you modify the two base monads to use the same `Left` type.  For example, we could normalize them to both use `ByteString`.  To do this, we first take `ByteString`'s `pack` function:

```
pack :: String -> ByteString
```

Then we lift it to work on the left value of an `EitherT`:

```
import Control.Error (fmapLT)  -- from the 'errors' package

fmapLT pack :: (Monad m) => EitherT String m r -> EitherT ByteString m r
```

Now we need to target that transformation to your `Consumer`'s base monad, using `hoist`:

```
hoist (fmapLT pack)
 :: (Monad m, Proxy p)
 => Consumer p a (EitherT String m) r -> Consumer p a (EitherT ByteString m) r
```

Now you can compose your consumer directly with your producer since they have the same base monad.

The second solution is the one Daniel Diaz Carrete proposed.  You instead get your two pipes to agree on a common monad transformer stack that contains both `EitherT` layers.  All you have to do is decide in which order to nest those two layers.

Let's imagine that you choose to layer the `EitherT String` transformer outside of the `EitherT ByteString` transformer.  That would mean that your final target monad transformer stack would be:

```
(Proxy p) => Session (EitherT String (EitherT ByteString p)) IO r
```

Now you need to promote both of your pipes to target that transformer stack.

For your `Consumer`, you need to insert an `EitherT ByteString` layer in between `EitherT String` and `IO` if you want to match that final monad transformer stack.  Creating the layer is easy: you just use `lift`, but you need to target that lift in between those two specific layers, so you use `hoist`, twice, because you need to skip over both the proxy monad transformer and the `EitherT String` monad transformer:

```
hoist (hoist lift) . consumer
 :: Proxy p => () -> Consumer p a (EitherT String (EitherT ByteString IO)) ()
```

For your `Producer`, you need to insert an `EitherT String` layer in between the proxy monad transformer and the `EitherT ByteString` transformer if you want to match the final monad transformer stack.  Again, creating the layer is easy: we just use `lift`, but you need to target that lift in between those two specific layers.  You just `hoist`, but this time you only use it once, since you only need to skip over the proxy monad transformer to nestle the `lift` in the right spot:

```
hoist lift . producer
 :: Proxy p => () -> Producer p a (EitherT String (EitherT ByteString IO)) r
```

Now your producer and consumer have the same monad transformer stack and you can compose them directly.

Now, you might wonder: Is this process of `hoist`ing `lift`s doing the "right thing"?  The answer is yes.  Part of the magic of category theory is that we can rigorously define what it means to correctly insert an "empty monad transformer layer" using `lift` and we can similarly rigorously define what it means to "target something in between two monad transformers" using `hoist` by specifying several theoretically-inspired laws and verifying that `lift` and `hoist` observe those laws.

Once we satisfy those laws, we can just ignore all the nitty gritty details of what exactly `lift` and `hoist` do.  Category theory frees us to work at a very high abstraction level where we just think in terms of "inserting lifts" spatially between monad transformers and the code magically translates our spatial intuition into the rigorously correct behavior.

My guess is that you probably want the first solution since you can then share error-handling between the producer and consumer in a single `EitherT` layer.

Comment: I think you have the wrong Daniel... to be fair, there are far too many to keep track of. ;]

Comment: Correct!  How embarrassing.  :)  I'll fix it.

Comment: Great answer, I could have marked this one as accepted as well. I should have put exceptions instead of `String` and `ByteString` to resemble more what I was really trying to do. The first approach would use `toException` instead of `pack`, but I still not sure which way will make handling different exceptions easier.

Comment: Don't worry about which one you choose to accept.  All that matters is that you learned something. :)  Also, now I know how to clarify the pipe docs better.